# Why app crashing while set a value to NSManagedObject in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data

Hi in my application I am setting the value for NSManagedObject while I am trying to set a value app is crashing.Here is the code and error message.

```
 NSManagedObject *object3 = [threadManagedObjectContext objectWithID:[object1 objectID]] ;

  for (int i=0;i<[array1 count];i++)
        {

            NSDictionary *keyValue=[array1 objectAtIndex:i];

            [object3 setValue:[[keyValue allValues] lastObject] forKey:[[keyValue allKeys] lastObject]] ;
        }


    Error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason:was mutated while being enumerated
```

Can any one please help me.

Comment: are you written the above code base in a loop statement?

Answer (score 0):

```
You can try below solution for updating the object...


NSManagedObject *object3 = [threadManagedObjectContext objectWithID:[object1 objectID]] ;
int i=0;

  for (NSDictionary *keyValue in array1) 
    {
       [[object3 setValue:[[keyValue allValues] lastObject] forKey:[[keyValue allKeys] lastObject]] ;i++;

    }

    NSError *error;
    bool result = [[fetchedResultsController threadManagedObjectContext] save:&error];

    if (!result) {
       NSLog(@" error saving context, %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
    }
```

In your code while Looping/Enumerating you are setting value..So it is crashing...!

Hope it helps you....

Comment: HI Vidhyanand thanks a lot for your reply. I edit my question can you please check once and let me know where I have to do chnages to avoid crash.

Comment: Hi Vidhyanand I want to change the value for a key. I don't want to insert new object.

Comment: I modified my answer..PLZ try it..!

Comment: Hi vidhyanand thx a lot for ur response. But here if we see my question I am fetching a dictionary from an array and assigning the dic key value pair to NSManaged object can you please check ur code..

Comment: I modified my answer..by using NSDictionary..!

Comment: Thx and one more concern that is in array1 all objects are dictionaries only not NSManagedObject objects.

Comment: Hi vidhyanand can you please help me.

Comment: Once try with my modified answer..@user3341324

Comment: Hi Vidhyanad Actually the code is like this only in past later I changed as such above. Still app is crashing.

Answer (score 0):

In your code (not the provided) , you're changing a collection while looping/iterating.

**Example (not allowed):**

```
for (MyClass *myClassObj in collectionOfMyClass) {

   [myClassObj setClassVar: aVar]
}
```

**Solution:**

Make a temporary collection of the objects you want to set. Set all of them back outside of your loop.

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray  alloc] init];

for (MyClass *myClassObj in collectionOfMyClass) {

        [tempArray addObject:aVar];
 }

[myClassObj setClassVars: tempArray];
```